# How to show Spanish Text in TextView?

Tags: android

I have the following  code and i try to show text in text-view which in Spanish. When I run app then it showing ? at some places. Can anyone tell me detailed procedure for showing Spanish.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.information);
   textview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
       textview.setText(readTxt());
}

private String readTxt(){
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.info);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;
    try {
    i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1)
        {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your readTxt method is wrong.
You are returning a String representation of your `ByteArrayOutputStream` and not the actual String.

Try reading the input stream into a `ByteArrayInputStream` and then getting the byte array from it and on that return new `String(byteArray)`;

```
    private String readTxt(){               
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.info);
        InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            buffer.append(line);
            buffer.append("\n");
        }
        buffer.deleteCharAt(buffer.length() - 1); // Delete the last new line char
        // TODO: Don't forget to close all streams and readers
        return buffer.toString();   
    }
```

Comment: I cant get it properly.Can you give me some example or link so that I will refer that...

Comment: I've edited my answer. Note that I HAVEN'T TESTED the code and just wrote it here, but it should serve as an explanation for my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I try your logic but still it is not showing proper text.Please let me know or give me some link or tell another method.