# Gujarati text in Android is not displayed correctly

Tags: android, text, right-to-left

We are using Android 1.6, Java 1.6 and Eclipse Helios.

We are working on a transliteration and I am bit hanged with the complex text that is not displaying correctly in my android emulator as well as mobile. I googled for this and some guys also end up with same problem and they suggest to use the HarfBuzz. Could anyone please tell me how to use harfbuff or any other solution to my problem is welcome.

The ki કિ font is displaying wrongly in opposite direction:

[image: screenshot]

Not only ki. The font end up with 'i' is getting typed wrongly.

Comment: can you attach image link or image??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735636/how-to-show-spanish-text-in-textview is the same question

Comment: Hi i have attached the image <http://i56.tinypic.com/11rbst3.png>

Comment: No Dharmendra , thats not my actual problem , i am able to display the remaining gujarati text properly except the font ended with 'i' like ki,ji,gi,ri in gujarati .which is getting in opposite direction

Comment: Hi i have attached one more image for this .<http://i51.tinypic.com/10z1iiq.png> the font is resp a,aa,ji,gi,ri,ree . For ji,gi,ri alone is wrong remaining thing is correct font

Comment: check. http://www.google.com/transliterate/Gujarati

Comment: Hi from google transliteration , it seems that they are replacing ki font with kee when it is typed individually and when i typed for word ex: kiran the character is replaced again with ki.